# What constants make the integral equal to $1$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, constants

> What constants $a_1,a_2, \cdot \cdot \cdot, a_n \in \Bbb N $ make the following integral equal to $1$?

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{a_1e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^k(x)}+ \frac{a_2e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^{k-1}(x)}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{a_ne^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^2(x)}~dx$$

I found that for $a_1, \cdot \cdot \cdot, a_3$ being equal to $1,2,1$ the integral is $1.$
Also for $a_1, \cdot \cdot \cdot, a_5$ being equal to $1,6,8,4,1$ the integral is $1.$ I'm trying to see if the sequence follows some pattern.

Comment: How does $k$ relate to $n$?

Comment: @Barry I'm not sure. $k$ is a natural number

Comment: Well then, what value(s) of $k$ did you use for the integrals you found equal to $1$?

Comment: I used $k=2,3,4,$ to get the constants $1,2,1.$ And then I used $k=2,3,4,5,6$ to get constants $1,6,8,4,1$